# Battery drain while listening to network location updates

Tags: android, location, power-management

I have an application that is running as a background service and constantly listens to network updates (course location). The service itself doesn't hold any wake locks. The listening part looks like this:

`locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 120000, 3000F, this);`

My `onLocationChanged()` method is doing some very simple stuff (just calculating distance to a pre-configured location using `Location.distanceTo()`:

When looking into the battery stats, the application is a rock star – sometimes even more than the display.

CPU is not that bad but the "Stay Awake" part is very high.

Is there a way to prevent this?

I thought to use the `AlarmManager` to request an update every 2 minutes and then go to sleep after I get it, but I'm not sure that this is a good approach.

Also, I thought to detect when the device is in motion, but this will most probably be even a larger killer.

Comment: I have not done any programming which consumes battery, so your scenario looks interesting. I wonder if an application is running in background then why will the phone "stay awake". And the approach of waking it up every 2 min and then again asking it so sleep is not so good I too feel :|

Comment: you may refer this [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+blogspot%2FhsDu+%28Android+Developers+Blog%29) in android developers blog about good practices for getting user location in an android app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you answered your own question.

> I thought to use the AlarmManager to request an update every 2 minutes
>   and then go to sleep after I get it. Not sure though that its a good
>   approach.

That would be the best approach. But don't set it to two minutes, set it to 10 minutes intervals.

Comment: Just changed this to use AlarmManager - huge improvement. I expected that when requesting location updates with the same frequency Android OS will be smart enough to spare the battery...